# Live Stream Audio in Wavesurfer.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I need to plot a streaming audio which comes as buffers of 2 seconds. Besides that, I need to plot the audio and have features like play, pause, zoom and span.
Wavesurfer.js has most of these features except that it only plots for single/ static audio file. I need it to work for streaming audio too.
What tweak should I do?
Has anyone done anything like this before? Any other better alternatives?
Specification:
Plot a streaming wave file in colour. The user should be able to pause, play, zoom and span into the audio.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I am guessing you might be able to pull it off using the `audio` tag to get the stream and making that into a MediaElementSource. Once you have that data, you can plot it using something like http://stuartmemo.com/wavy-jones/. The zoom and pan can only work on data that has already streamed.